# Deconstructing if/else Python

Tags: python, parsing, syntax

I have a program that outputs some conditions like this (**this is the actual output, it is pseudo code**):

```
if ( first occurance of 'AB' <= -0.5 ) {
    return [ 0.]
} else {
    if ( number of products viewed <= 1.5 ) {
        if ( similarity to 'AB' <= 0.899999976158 ) {
            return [ 1.]
        } else {
            return [ 0.]
        }
    } else {
        if ( average time between actions <= 57.2111129761 ) {
            return [ 0.39145907]
        } else {
            return [ 0.10410805]
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get a more human readable(?)/deconstructed solution? ie:

```
( first occurance of 'AB' > -0.5 ) * (( number of products viewed <= 1.5 ) * ( similarity to 'AB' <= 0.899999976158 ))+((( number of products viewed > 1.5 ) * ( average time between actions <= 57.2111129761 ))
```

(I do already have code that can change "<=" to ">", but beyond that I can't seem to isolate each if condition in the right order.

EDIT: code used to get current output (not minimal example I'm afraid)

```
def get_code(tree, feature_names, tabdepth=0):
    left      = tree.tree_.children_left
    right     = tree.tree_.children_right
    threshold = tree.tree_.threshold
    features  = [feature_names[i] for i in tree.tree_.feature]
    value = tree.tree_.value
    f=[]

    def recurse(left, right, threshold, features, node, f, tabdepth=0):
            if (threshold[node] != -2):
                    print('\t' * tabdepth + 'if ( ' + features[node] + ' <= ' + str(threshold[node]) + ' ) {')
                    f.append('%' * tabdepth+'if ( ' + features[node] + ' <= ' + str(threshold[node]) + ' ) {')
                    if left[node] != -1:
                            recurse (left, right, threshold, features,left[node], f, tabdepth+1)
                    print('\t' * tabdepth+'} else {')
                    f.append('%' * tabdepth+'} else {')
                    if right[node] != -1:
                            recurse (left, right, threshold, features,right[node], f, tabdepth+1)
                    print('\t' * tabdepth + '}')
            else:
                    print('\t' * tabdepth + 'return ' + str(value[node][0]))
                    f.append('%' * tabdepth + 'return ' + str(value[node][0]))

    recurse(left, right, threshold, features, 0, f)
```

Comment: I guess 'more human readable' is subjective...

Comment: @DeepSpace yeeah... I wasn't sure how to phrase it otherwise, but at least remove it from the if/else form

Comment: Your current output is quite human readable. I can confirm that as a human.

Comment: If someone has a better way of phrasing it I'll take it

Comment: Your question makes no sense, the human readable version returns values whilst the unreadable mess is trying to multiply booleans

Comment: So you have a program that outputs some code in an arbitrary syntax (Python and C mix ?) and want to change its format? Why not output it the "right" way to begin with?

Comment: you can try `elif` for better readability for i guess

Comment: @chepner I know... I want to parse the pseudo code to get the result I want

Comment: @Sayse it's boolean algebra,  I don't want to feed the result back into a program https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Comment: Do you want to print the structure of if/else control structure?

Comment: @TusharAggarwal idealy I'd prefer the equation form, but the structure could be a step in the right direction

Comment: @Chris_Rands no, that's just my output, it **isn't actual code**

Comment: [expanding on @DeepSpace's comment:] You *could* write a parser for the pseudo-code if/else format, but that would be a fair bit of work just to (more or less) rebuild a tree-structure that you *already had* when the Python code was running. It would be less work to ignore the pseudo-code intermediary, and just modify the Python code to go straight from the `tree` structure to the algebraic format that you want. So is there a reason you can't do that? Or do you just really want to write a parser?

Comment: @MichaelDyck I'd really just want to right the parser as I'd need to replicate this on other similar if/else sets

Comment: Ah, so you need to convert pre-existing if/else pseudocode samples, and you no longer have access to the Pythonic tree-structures from which they were generated?

Comment: A parser is do-able, but it's unclear how the desired output formula is supposed to relate to the input if/else pseudo-code, because it can't always be equivalent. A Boolean algebra formula can only return 0 or 1, but your example pseudo-code returns other values, 0.39145907 and 0.10410805. What is the the formula supposed to return in such cases?

Comment: @MichaelDyck Indeed. In this case I was going to round the higher of the two values to 1 and round the other to zero (believe me when I say that it makes sense in this context)

Comment: Okay, but what if there isn't two floats to compare? Imagine that on line 2 of your pseudo-code example, instead of `return [ 0.]`, it was `return [ 0.23 ]`. How would you decide whether to round 0.23 up or down?

Comment: Or what if you have two floats, but they have the same value? And do the floats always fall in the range [0,1]?

Comment: @MichaelDyck that's a good point, though in theory only the last two values should be non-0 and non-1, and in the case where they are equal, ideally the last if would be removed

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to write code to:

1. parse any instance of the if/else pseudo-code, building a tree-structure; then
2. recursively traverse the tree-structure, generating the desired boolean formula.

For the conversion, the main idea is:

```
convert( if C then T else E )
==>
C * convert(T) + !C * convert(E)
```

If you want more specific help, you should probably ask a more specific question.